# Interfaces with params

Tags: java, interface

I am using the same interface in 3 different classes,

however, these 3 classes need to have different parameters to deal with,and all must be named

for example i have this interface

```
public interface ITest<T>{

 public T test1();
 public T test2();
 public T test3();
}
```

and i have 3 classes

A,B,C which implement all ITest with different T type param

however, i need A class to have this method:

```
test1(String a, String b);
```

class B to have this method :

```
test1();
```

class C to have this method:

```
test1(boolean b);
```

is this possible using the same interface? or do i need 3 different interfaces for these classes ?

Note: I could write my interface like this: (assuming all types in the brackets are the same)

```
public interface ITest<T,S>{
 public T test1(S...params);
 public T test2();
 public T test3();

}
```

however, this would mean that 1: all params must be the same, 2 in the methods that dont need any params, there are still params

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `test1()` has a different signature imho, so I won't use the same interface. What is the benefit of the var arg method, is it really useful or more limiting? Don't create interfaces just from similar method signatures but from equal use cases.

This may be a good example to use the interface segregation principle ([ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)) with the following interfaces:

```
public interface ITest<T> {
  public T test2();
  public T test3();
}

public interface ITestA<T> {
  public T test1(String a, String b);
}

public interface ITestB<T> {
  public T test1();
}

public interface ITestB<T> {
  public T test1(boolean b);
}
```

So an implementation can implement the appropriate interfaces (I'm not sure about the right generic params of the implementations in your example):

```
class A implements ITest<String>, ITestA<String> {...}

class B implements ITest<Integer>, ITestB<Integer> {...}

class C implements ITest<MyClass>, ITestC<MyClass> {...}
```

But be sure you need the different methods as an interface, Adam Bien would say ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The 3 methods test1 from your example are completely different methods as they don't share the same set of parameters.

Same interface means a set of methods which are shared by a few classes (A, B, C in your example). So here you don't have the same interface in your 3 classes (as their test1 methods are different). You have 3 different interfaces.

OK, if your 3 classes share the same test2 and test3 methods (but not the test1 method),
then just take the test1 method out of your interface.